# How to identify code responsible for, and style a turning wheel animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

The specimen of interest is a live webpage at https://store.ashenglowgaming.com/

When customer clicks on an Add to Cart button on the home page, an animation triggers of a turning progress wheel, which I want to target for styling, as I need to override its default color with the color `#d53600` and implement a glow to the turning wheel using whatever means available.

[image]

This example goes beyond a simple minimal example; it's an real application question, and frankly I have no idea how the turning wheel is being implemented, whether I can style it by CSS, or I must override some JavaScript somewhere.

The question is, firstly, how can I identify the code responsible for the turning wheel?  All the information I know how to extract from browser developer tools are the HTML and CSS, which is provided as follows:

**HTML AND CSS**:

```css
  button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"],
.button,
.added_to_cart,
.widget a.button,
.site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart a.button {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-color: #eeeeee;
  color: #333333;
}

1516799947index.css:2 .added_to_cart,
.button,
button,
input[type=button],
input[type=reset],
input[type=submit] {
  border: 0;
  background: 0 0;
  background-color: #43454b;
  border-color: #43454b;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .6180469716em 1.41575em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
```

```html
<a rel="nofollow" href="/?add-to-cart=116" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="116" data-product_sku="" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>
```

If I haven't provided some detail of consequence, please ask before down-voting - it is not out of laziness, but rather that I'm just out of my depth and I'm a non-coder trying my best to cope here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find it for you.  To change the color you should change the following.

```
.button.loading:after {
color: #FFFFFF; /* This is the default color */
}
```

If you want to play around with the specifics of the animation then you should toy with

```
button.loading:after, input[type="button"].loading:after, 
input[type="reset"].loading:after, input[type="submit"].loading:after, 
.button.loading:after, .added_to_cart.loading:after {
display: inline-block;
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
font-size: inherit;
text-rendering: auto;
content: "\f110";
-webkit-animation: fa-spin .75s linear infinite;
animation: fa-spin .75s linear infinite;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
font-size: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -10px;
margin-top: -10px;
}
```

To change the background color of the button while loading is active you should change the following

```
.button.loading:hover {
background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another small detail: notice how there is a grey background hover if the user mouses over the button while the animation is active?  Which selector is relevant for styling that?

Answer (score 0):

People usually add the spinner image or gif during saving of data or when it needs to talk to the server via ajax and I see ajax was used when they click add to cart.

```
 $.ajax({
  // your ajax code
  beforeSend: function(){
       $('.loader').show()
   },
  complete: function(){
       $('.loader').hide();
  }
 });
```

so you could look for an loading or loader class or look in the ajax javascript itself to get a clue of where it's being called.

Comment: Is it not possible to get this information from browsers' developer tools?  Otherwise, as a non-coder, it's going to be difficult for me to know where the relevant code is...

Comment: It's possible, I would go to html and ctrl+f for an <img> that has class or other attribute named loader or loading.